# Cant get this to run PAYROLL PROJECT java

Tags: java

```
package EmployeePayAppMRM;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class java 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String fullName;
    String itemsSold;
    String valueItems;
    double basePay;
    double totalPay;
    double valueSold;
    int numberSold;
    final double ITEM_MIN = 10;
    final int VALUE_MIN = 2500;
    final int BONUS = 500;

    firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter employee's first name:");
    lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter employee's last name:");
    fullName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter base pay for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":");
       basePay = Double.parseDouble(fullName);
    itemsSold = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter number of items sold for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":");
       totalPay = Double.parseDouble(fullName);
    fullName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter value of items sold for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":");
       valueSold = Double.parseDouble(fullName);

       basePay = 1000;

       if ( itemsSold > ITEM_MIN)                   //ERROR HERE (bad operand)
           totalPay = (basePay + BONUS);

       else if (valueSold >= VALUE_MIN)
           totalPay = (basePay + BONUS);

       else 
           totalPay = basePay;




      System.out.println("this" + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + "will be paid" + totalPay "for selling" + itemsSold "items valued at $" + valueSold);          //ERROR HERE


System.exit(0);


}

}
```

Comment: `itemsSold` is a string, `ITEM_MIN` is a number, you can't directly compare them

Comment: You may now think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is about types, for the second you just miss some `+`

- `itemsSold` is a `String`
- `ITEM_MIN` is a `double`

Do like this, of parse it before

```
if(Double.parseDouble(itemsSold) > ITEM_MIN)
    totalPay = (basePay + BONUS);
```

---

Finally, you don't need to define the variable and do the assignement later, just do it at the same time, once reoganisating all :

```
final double ITEM_MIN = 10;
final int VALUE_MIN = 2500;
final int BONUS = 500;

String firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter employee's first name:");
String lastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter employee's last name:");
String fullName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter base pay for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":");
double itemsSold = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter number of items sold for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":"));
double valueSold = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(" Enter value of items sold for " + firstName + " " + lastName + ":"));

double totalPay = 0;
double basePay = 1000;
if (itemsSold > ITEM_MIN) {
    totalPay = (basePay + BONUS);
} else if (valueSold >= VALUE_MIN) {
    totalPay = (basePay + BONUS);
} else {
    totalPay = basePay;
}
System.out.println("this" + firstName + " " + lastName + " " + "will be paid" + totalPay + "for selling" + itemsSold + "items valued at $" + valueSold);
```